# How to calculate total hours?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I am trying to calculate total hours based on "employeeId". I couldn't figure out how to write logic for this. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Expected Result,

```
[
    {

        "employeeId": "105",
        "totalHours": "2:45"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "777",
        "totalHours": "2:15"
    }
]
```

Response From Ajax Call

```
[
    {
        "employeeId": "105",
        "totalHours": "1:30"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "777",
        "totalHours": "1:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "105",
        "totalHours": "1:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "777",
        "totalHours": "1:00"
    }
]
```

My Code

```
var jrr = new Array();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: '/common/services/general/basicOperations/getDataByModelUsingGetMethod',
      method: 'GET',
      params : {
        actionId : 'payroll',
        dataJson : '{"aspectType":"Payroll Profile"}'
      },
      success: function(response){
        try{
          var response = response.responseText;
          var resObj = Ext.decode(response);
          for(var j = 0; j < resObj.data.length; j++)
              {
                 for(var k = 0; k < resObj.data[j].payrolltransactionDetail.length; k++) 
                 {
                    jrr.push(resObj.data[j].payrolltransactionDetail[k]);
                 }
              }
              console.log(JSON.stringify(jrr, null, 4));
        }
        catch(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      },
      failure: function(response){
        deferred.reject("Error Fetching.");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I would handle this in the db query.

Comment: I am using MongoDB.

Comment: Do you control the back-end or are you just given an API to work with?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have control.

Comment: The response in your code example seems to be different than the one you posted above. Where did payrolltransactionDetail come from? or does each cell in it contain what you gave as an example?

Comment: Jecoms, We are using node.js in backend. Do you know how to write query for this using MongoDB?

Comment: Look into [db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Comment: kabaus, This is the response, [
    {
        "_id": "d4fd0201-286a-4c30-882d-5c3b847285fd",
        "fromDate": "11/01/2016",
        "toDate": "11/30/2016",
        "payDate": "",
        "processedDate": "",
        "refDataName": "",
        "payrolltransactionDetail": [
            {
                "employeeId": "105",
                "totalHours": "1:30"
            },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using js functional programming. You can transform the data to your desired output using just the reduce function. If you cannot change your query result using some kind of aggregation on the server side  then you can implement something akin to the below.

```js
var input = [
    {
        "employeeId": "105",
        "totalHours": "1:46"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "777",
        "totalHours": "1:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "105",
        "totalHours": "1:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "777",
        "totalHours": "1:00"
    }
]

var obj = input.reduce( function(init, e){
    //if aggregating init object doesn't have the employee then add the employeeId (key) and time (value)
    if (init[e["employeeId"]] == undefined){
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {
             hours: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]),
             minutes: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1])
         };
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = e["totalHours"];
         return init;
     //otherwise add to the existing employeeId the hour and minute values, while remembering to carry the extra hour if minutes exceed 59.
      }else{
         init[e["employeeId"]].hours += 
             (parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]) +
             Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + 
             parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))/60));

         init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = 
             (init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + 
             parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))%60;

         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = 
             init[e["employeeId"]].minutes > 9 ? 
                 init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes :
                 init[e["employeeId"]].hours + 
                 ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes;
         return init;
      }
  }, {});

var arr = [];
for (var prop in obj) arr.push({employeeId: prop, totalHours: obj[prop].timeString});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This produces an incorrect result, "3:01" for employee `105`. It also doesn't match the format asked for in the OP.

Comment: I changed it to test it.

Comment: Regardless, it still doesn't match the format OP asked for.

Comment: I edited it...still your downvote was unwarranted. The fact that my object could so trivially be changed into what OP was asking for makes it a de facto useful answer. I didn't even notice he had an array at first.

Comment: Now it's unwarranted, because you answered the question.

Comment: I think your definition of "useful" needs widening. If I got spoon-fed examples like this at work then I would be 10X more productive, regardless of whether the example output wasn't exactly the same to the property....as long as it contains all the relevant info in intuitive arrangement then I'd call that a useful answer....but to each his own. SO isn't a homework portal

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation. I think it's cleaner than some of the other answers:

```
function calc(data) {
    const seen = {};
    const result = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
        const id = item.employeeId;
        if (!seen.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            seen[id] = result.length;
            result.push({
                employeeId: id,
                minutes: 0
            });
        }
        const idx = seen[id];
        const parts = item.totalHours.split(':');
        result[idx].minutes += (parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60) + parseInt(parts[1]);
    });

    result.forEach(item => {
        const minutes = item.minutes;
        delete item.minutes;
        item.totalHours = Ext.String.leftPad(Math.floor(minutes / 60), 2, '0') 
                            + ':' + Ext.String.leftPad(minutes % 60, 2, '0');
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(calc([{
    "employeeId": "105",
    "totalHours": "1:30"
}, {
    "employeeId": "777",
    "totalHours": "1:15"
}, {
    "employeeId": "105",
    "totalHours": "1:15"
}, {
    "employeeId": "777",
    "totalHours": "1:00"
}]));
```

Comment: I explained why I downvoted. A downvote is because "This answer is not useful". Are you saying this is not useful?

Comment: Your answer is not useful because you don't explain anything that you are doing.

Comment: I think your definition of "useful" needs widening. If I got spoon-fed examples like this at work then I would be 10X more productive, regardless of whether the example output wasn't exactly the same to the property....as long as it contains all the relevant info in intuitive arrangement then I'd call that a useful answer....but to each his own. SO isn't a homework portal

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Expecting input to be your custom object
var output={};
for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
el = input[i];
a=output[el.id];
a.employeId=el.employeId;
a.totalHours=a.totalHours||"0:0";
b=el.totalHours.split(":");
c=a.totalHours.split(":");
b[0]=+b[0]+c[0];
if(b[1]+c[1]>60){
b[0]++;
}
b[1]=(+b[1]+c[1])%60;
a.totalHours=b.join(":");
}
```

The result is not exactly what youve expected. I dont wanted to search the employe id in the array each times:

```
{
105:{
   employeid:105;
   totalHours:"15:20";
 }
 }
```

Comment: SO isnt meant to always give a full answer. Sometimes answers are there to guide the OP into the right direction...